# How can I remove the key from array in php?

Tags: php

I have date array in which I want to replace curli brackets instead of square brackets, following is array

```
{
    "2018": {
        "02": {
            "consecutive": [
                [20, 21]
            ],
            "non_consecutive": []
        },
        "03": {
            "consecutive": [],
            "non_consecutive": [29]
        }
    },
    "2019": {
        "07": {
            "consecutive": [
                [30, 31]
            ],
            "non_consecutive": []
        },
        "10": {
            "consecutive": [],
            "non_consecutive": [13]
        },
        "11": {
            "consecutive": [
                [5, 6]
            ],
            "non_consecutive": []
        },
        "12": {
            "consecutive": [
                [9, 10],
                [24, 25, 26]
            ],
            "non_consecutive": [12, 20]
        }
    }
}
```

And I have following script which is generating above array

```
$datesArray = [
    "2018-02-20",
    "2018-02-21",
    "2018-03-29",
    "2019-07-30",
    "2019-07-31",
    "2019-10-13",
    "2019-11-05",
    "2019-11-06",
    "2019-12-09",
    "2019-12-10",
    "2019-12-12",
    "2019-12-20",
    "2019-12-24",
    "2019-12-25",
    "2019-12-26"
];

$conseq = [];
foreach($datesArray as $current_date) {
    $eachMonth = date('m',strtotime($current_date));
    $eachYear = date('Y',strtotime($current_date));
    if(!isset($conseq[$eachYear][$eachMonth])){
        $conseq[$eachYear][$eachMonth] = [];
    }
    $conseq[$eachYear][$eachMonth][] = $current_date;
}
foreach($conseq as $key => $value){
    $currentYear = $key;
    foreach($value as $current_month => $dates){
        usort($dates,function($a,$b){
            return strtotime($a) - strtotime($b);
        });
        $consecutive_added_set = [];
        $consecutive_array = [];
        $temp = [];
        $temp[] = (int)date('d',strtotime($dates[0]));
        for($i=1;$i<count($dates);++$i){
            if(strtotime($dates[$i]) - strtotime($dates[$i - 1]) === 86400){ // 1 day gap(86400 seconds)
                $temp[] = (int)date('d',strtotime($dates[$i]));
                $consecutive_added_set[$dates[$i-1]] = true;
                $consecutive_added_set[$dates[$i]] = true;
            }else{
                if(count($temp) > 1){
                    /*$consecutive_array['slot_'.$i] = $temp;*/  
                    $consecutive_array[] = $temp;   
                }
                $temp = [];
                $temp[] = (int)date('d',strtotime($dates[$i]));
            }
        }
        if(count($temp) > 1){ // include the last consecutiveness match of dates as well(corner case)
            /*$consecutive_array['slot_'.$i] = $temp;*/
            $consecutive_array[] = $temp;
        }
        $conseq[$currentYear][$current_month] = []; // reset the array structure 
        $conseq[$currentYear][$current_month]['consecutive'] = $consecutive_array;
        $conseq[$currentYear][$current_month]['non_consecutive'] = [];
        foreach($dates as $current_date){
            if(!isset($consecutive_added_set[$current_date])){ // skip all dates which were included for consecutiveness
                $conseq[$currentYear][$current_month]['non_consecutive'][] = (int)date('d',strtotime($current_date));
            }
        }
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
echo json_encode($conseq);
echo '</pre>';
```

Above script returns sub arrays with square brackets, but it not accessible in unity, so i need to change it from square to curli brackets.

**My desire array is following**

```
{
    "2018": {
        "02": {
            "consecutive": {
                [20, 21]
            },
            "non_consecutive": {}
        },
        "03": {
            "consecutive": {},
            "non_consecutive": {29}
        }
    },
    "2019": {
        "07": {
            "consecutive": {
                [30, 31]
            }
            "non_consecutive": {}
        },
        "10": {
            "consecutive": {},
            "non_consecutive": {13}
        },
        "11": {
            "consecutive": {}
                [5, 6]
            },
            "non_consecutive": {}
        },
        "12": {
            "consecutive": {}
                [9, 10],
                [24, 25, 26]
            },
            "non_consecutive": {12, 20}
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried a lot to do it, but failed. Can someone kindly guide me how can I do that? I would appreciate.

Comment: @vivek_23 can you post your answer here if possible

Comment: Yes, but please clear the doubt. What if there were more than 1 possibility for consecutive dates, like "2019-02-04","2019-02-05" and then like "2019-02-09","2019-02-10","2019-02-11"? Or will there be only 1 continuous stream of consecutive dates?

Comment: @vivek_23 yes it should be like this like this `["2019-02-04","2019-02-05"],["2019-02-09","2019-02-10","2019-02-11"]`

Comment: In that case, as you said,  then we could also have individual elements in it, so there wouldn't be need for `non-consecutive`.

Comment: @vivek_23 for `non-consecutive` dates I would like to have one array only like this `non-consecutive ["2019-02-01","2019-02-10"]`

Comment: So you mean it should go under `consecutive` only if the length is of size `2` or more, else it should come under `non-consecutive`?

Comment: @vivek_23 yes very simple consecutive dates should be in consecutive array and non consecutive dates should be non consecutive array

Comment: @vivek_23 whenever you done then kindly share with me, I might not come online for few hours. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I will be adding an answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$dateOnly = [
        "2019-02-02",
        "2019-02-04",
        "2019-02-05",
        "2019-02-26",
        "2019-03-03",
        "2019-03-04",
        "2019-03-05",
        "2019-03-07",
        "2019-08-02",
        "2019-08-05",
        "2019-08-06",
        "2019-08-07",
        "2019-08-08",
        "2019-08-10",
        "2019-08-15",
        "2019-08-16",
        "2019-08-17",
    ];


    $conseq = array(); 

    foreach($dateOnly as $current_date) {
        $eachMonth = date('m-Y',strtotime($current_date));
        if(!isset($conseq[$eachMonth])){
            $conseq[$eachMonth] = [];
        }
        $conseq[$eachMonth][] = $current_date;
    }


    foreach($conseq as $current_month => $dates){
          usort($dates,function($a,$b){
              return strtotime($a) - strtotime($b);
          });


          $consecutive_added_set = [];
          $consecutive_array = [];
          $temp = [];
          $temp[] = $dates[0];

          for($i=1;$i<count($dates);++$i){
            if(strtotime($dates[$i]) - strtotime($dates[$i - 1]) === 86400){ // 1 day gap(86400 seconds)
                $temp[] = $dates[$i];
                $consecutive_added_set[$dates[$i-1]] = true;
                $consecutive_added_set[$dates[$i]] = true;
            }else{
                if(count($temp) > 1){
                    $consecutive_array[] = $temp;   
                }
                $temp = [];
                $temp[] = $dates[$i];
            }
          }

          if(count($temp) > 1){ // include the last consecutiveness match of dates as well(corner case)
            $consecutive_array[] = $temp;
          }


          $conseq[$current_month] = []; // reset the array structure 
          $conseq[$current_month]['consecutive'] = $consecutive_array;
          $conseq[$current_month]['non-consecutive'] = [];

          foreach($dates as $current_date){
              if(!isset($consecutive_added_set[$current_date])){ // skip all dates which were included for consecutiveness
                  $conseq[$current_month]['non-consecutive'][] = $current_date; 
              }
          }
    }


    print_r($conseq);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/2PWu6

- We first collect all dates in their respective month keys in `$conseq` as shown in the below snippet.

**Grouping:**

```
$conseq = array(); 

foreach($dateOnly as $current_date) {
    $eachMonth = date('m-Y',strtotime($current_date));
    if(!isset($conseq[$eachMonth])){
        $conseq[$eachMonth] = [];
    }
    $conseq[$eachMonth][] = $current_date;
}
```

- Now that we have grouped, we iterate over `$conseq` again and look for grouping by consecutive dates and non consecutive dates.
- For that, we first [usort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) for each month as shown below.

  ```
    usort($dates,function($a,$b){
         return strtotime($a) - strtotime($b);
    });
  ```
- Now, all is left is to loop over the dates and check if previous one is a day before the current one. If yes, they go to the same group, else they could probably belong to the new group.
- `$consecutive_added_set` in the above code only keeps track of dates already for `consecutive` so that we don't add it again for `non-consecutive`.
- Rest is to just restructure our `$conseq` accordingly for the `$current_month` which is done in the below snippet.

**Restructure:**

```
$conseq[$current_month] = []; // reset the array structure 
$conseq[$current_month]['consecutive'] = $consecutive_array;
$conseq[$current_month]['non-consecutive'] = [];

foreach($dates as $current_date){
  if(!isset($consecutive_added_set[$current_date])){ // skip all dates which were included for consecutiveness
      $conseq[$current_month]['non-consecutive'][] = $current_date; 
  }
}
```

Comment: The only thing is if we can add year array as well, like now we have `"02-2019"`. I want to one more `"2019"`

Comment: @ImranAbbas Glad to help. Yes, you could add year as well if you like.

Comment: is this possible if we show just date `26` instead of  `2019-02-26`

Comment: @ImranAbbas yes, just do something like this `date("d",strtotime("2019-02-26"));`

Comment: `consecutive` array has double square brackets, can we make first one `{..}` instead of `square` bracket